# Unable to change kernel into Python 3 in Azure Data Studio

Tags: python-3.x, azure-data-studio

Trying to implement Python code in Azure data studio

```
Failed to change kernel. Kernel SQL will be used. Error was: Notebook process exited prematurely with error code: 1. StdErr Output: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\subin\AppData\Local\Programs\Azure Data Studio\resources\app\extensions\notebook\resources\pythonScripts\startNotebook.py", line 1, in <module>
    import notebook.notebookapp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.notebookapp'
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I am trying to change kernel from SQL to python in Azure data studio, I got the same error:

[image]

When I select `New python installation` as install type python is installing in below path.

[image]

Because of above python location I am getting above error. I tried attaching to the Python.exe that Anaconda installed in my user directory as mentioned below.

[image]

Then the kernel changed, and notebook run successfully.

[image]